# Magento randomly enters maintenance mode 3 times in one week. HELP

Tags: maintenance

My store randomly goes into maintenance mode. How can I stop it from doing this? It's happened 3 times in one week.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to create staging system for you instance. Enable the Magento Error log print  from  Backend .

If it it create  YourMagentoDir/var/system.log and  YOurMagentoDir/var/exception.log then must be some issue in your instance. and s start Debugging the System by follow Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store.

If this debug is not given solution then it might be server site issue.